# How do I route from Spring Cloud Gateway to a webflux endpoint in a FilterFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

Spring Cloud Gateway has a [ForwardRoutingFilter](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#forward-routing-filter)

> The ForwardRoutingFilter looks for a URI in the exchange attribute ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR. If the URL has a forward scheme (such as forward:///localendpoint), it uses the Spring DispatcherHandler to handle the request.

I tried the following

```java
exchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, URI.create("forward:///debug"));
return chain.filter(exchange);
```

But it seems to still be routing to the original service rather than my endpoint

The routes are defined by discovery as follows

```java
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          predicates:
            - name: Path
              args:
                patterns: "metadata['path']"
          filters:
            - RemoveRequestHeader='Cookie'
            # Prevent propagation of traces
            - RemoveRequestHeader='X-B3-TraceId'
            - RemoveRequestHeader='X-Trace-ID'
            - name: Retry
              args:
                retries: 3
              methods:
                - GET
            - name: RewritePath
              args:
                regexp: "metadata['path.regexp']"
                replacement: "metadata['path.replacement']"
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: "'resilience'"
                fallbackUri: "'forward:/unavailable'"
            # The Grpc is the one that contains the filter
            - name: Grpc 
              args:
                serviceId: serviceId
                host: host
                useGrpc: "metadata['protocol'] == 'grpc'"
                port: port
```

UPDATE: my workaround for now.

```
exchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_SCHEME_PREFIX_ATTR, "grpc");
```

Then I check whether I would process in a GlobalFilter

```
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

    if (!isAccepted(exchange)) {
      return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
...
  private boolean isAccepted(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return ("grpc".equals(exchange.getAttribute(GATEWAY_SCHEME_PREFIX_ATTR)))
```

Related code:

- [GrpcGatewayFilterFactory](https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/78ad12e7db4198fbedd94d2b2a4e87f5ae5ff187/gateway/src/main/java/net/trajano/swarm/gateway/grpc/GrpcGatewayFilterFactory.java#L51)
- [ServerStreamingGrpcGlobalFilter](https://github.com/trajano/spring-cloud-demo/blob/78ad12e7db4198fbedd94d2b2a4e87f5ae5ff187/gateway/src/main/java/net/trajano/swarm/gateway/grpc/ServerStreamingGrpcGlobalFilter.java#L236)

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to make it work?

Comment: no I put my workaround in the OP